# How to remove this picture and turn the header back to default

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I need to remove this logo (GA ) and let the standard way, but do not know where I can do it..[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the logo, you will need to have administrative rights and head over to the Office 365 admin center.

In the left side navigation, select **Company Profile** and then select **Custom theming**. From here you can delete the custom logo.

[Customize the Office 365 theme for your organization](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Customize-the-Office-365-theme-for-your-organization-8275da91-7a48-4591-94ab-3123a3f79530)